# Redireccionamiento de una página a través de .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Quiero redireccionar `www.mipagina.net` a, por ejemplo, `www.mipagina.net/forums`.

¿Cómo haría para poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias (demasiadas) formas de hacerlo.
Una forma que te permite jugar con diferentes condiciones es usando una [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) con el flag [`[R]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) para redireccionar:

```python
RewriteEngine On

# Redireccionar de / a forums
RewriteRule ^$ forums [R=302,L]
```

- Subí una demo a un hosting gratuito: http://mariano.uphero.com/142045

Comment: Osea, no tengo una carpeta "forums" porque el blog es creado con buddypress

Comment: Que podría hacer? si intento redireccionar el www.mipagina.com a www.mipagina.com/algo .. quiero que cuando alguien entre a esa dirección www.mipagina.com se vaya a www.mipagina.com/algo

Comment: No se puede redireccionar a un link y que ese link sea www.mipagina.com/algo ?

Comment: Podría ser :

Redirect 302 / /https://www.mipagina.com/algo ?

Comment: Usar eso me lleva a https://mipagina.com/algoalgoalgoalgo.... Que podría hacer? :c

Comment: @ElRincóndeAlex Edité la respuesta con una versión que te va a funcionar.